# Electro-static potential of a capacitor during a transient?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, capacitance, basic

How would I calculate the electro-static potential for this simple circuit during the transient (during the time the capacitor charges)? Do I just use Ohm's law?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFMcFa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My thought process was as follows:

- We know when the capacitor is charged it will have a "charge" of `1V * 1μF` (Psi aka. Q)
- So we have a current (`I`) of the value `Psi / Δt` during the transient
- `I = e / R` → `e = I * R` (`e` is the potential, aka. voltage, of the capacitor and `R` is the resistance of the conductor)

I wrote down my full thought-process here: http://circuits.icidasset.com/circuits/01-basics/002-capacitor

**Does this seem correct, or is there a better way?**

Comment: As drawn you have only 'ideal' components. You forgot to add the inductance the circuit certainly has.  The initial charge on the capacitor is zero, not 1V*1uF (*10^-6). The initial voltage is zero. Adding a step voltage of 1V from a perfect source into this ideal circuit with no resistance but **finite inductance** due to the loop nature of the circuit (not shown on your diagram)  would produce oscillation and bring about the destruction of the Universe. Add a small series resistance (say) 1 ohm and this will bring the circuit back into reality. Then you can use the conventional equations.

Comment: Where is R in your circuit and what is the "electro-static potential" you are trying to calculate?

Comment: @JImDearden Thanks. Yeah I meant the value when the capacitor charged (the condition after the charge). And the conductor has resistance and inductance, has it not? `R` in my equations would be the resistance of the conductor.

Comment: @Andyaka Updated the question, R is the resistance of the conductor. And the electro-static potential is the voltage of the capacitor during the transient.

Comment: **You need to show the resistance in the circuit diagram**. There are three sources of resistance. The voltage source (because it can't supply infinite current), the connecting wire (because we aren't using a superconductor)  and the internal series resistance (ESR) of the capacitor. These can be lumped together and shown as one resistor.  Also, a capacitor never reaches the final value of the voltage. We assume its fully charged after 5 time constants (>99%) of final voltage. For a time constant you need a value for R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capacitor charges like this: -

[image]

The exact formula is: -

\$V_C = V_S(1-e^{-t/RC})\$

Comment: Thanks! Could you clarify what the last part of that formula (`e...`) exactly is?

Comment: "e" is 2.71828 i.e. the natural exponential number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)). "t" is time.